# Process Scheduling : How does kernel updates need_resched flag of current running process?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, scheduler, job-scheduling

Lets consider that in a **SMP** environment, A process P is being executed which is currently either in "**process context**" or in "**interrupt context**", Now after completing the task, While returning back to the  user space(from an **interrupt handler** or from a **system call**) or returning back to kernel space(from an **interrupt handler**) it checks if **need_resched** flag is set, If the flag is found to be set then **scheduler** will be invoked to allocate a deserving process to run on the current processor.

What I am not able to understand is that how/who does set the **need_resched** flag ? since this flag is local to each process.

And its obvious that the current processor can not update the **need_resched** flag since its busy executing the current process P. In this case how does code executing on another processor update this flag within process P ?

Platform : Linux on x86

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760&seqNum=3

Comment: That's the same book i have been reading but did not get the answer.

Comment: `the kernel provides the need_resched flag to signify whether a reschedule should be performed (See Table 3.2). This flag is set by scheduler_tick() when a process runs out of timeslice and by try_to_wake_up() when a process that has a higher priority than the currently running process is awakened.` ? [try_to_wake_up](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2397) [scheduler_tick](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3459)

Comment: `since its busy executing the current process P` - so the execution of the process stops because of an interrupt or system call and the execution transfers to kernel. Then it can do what it wants. Or in a multiprocessor setup, another processor can set the flag. I fail to see why another processor can't set the flag - it's just a flag, so it just writes to it. Maybe you should read up about [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) and such.